# Delete specific keywords and duplicate values in Excel fields

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with URL's written in the first column, and there's about 1000 rows per sheet.

Here's my problem: I want to make delete duplicate URL's, based on a keyword of my choosing.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove duplicate URLs in an Excel spreadsheet? If so, try searching for "Filter for unique records" in Excel help.

Comment: I've read this five times and have no idea what you're asking. Could you please clarify? I'd be happy to help once I know what you need!

Comment: I've suggested 'close - not a real question' because although there is a question in here, struggling to get out, it is not going to make it without considerable rewording.  I understand that English is not the OPs native language, but.  I think @Jeffrey Kemp may be on the right track, but we need some assistance - perhaps a diagram? - before we can provide any help.  The subject might be "Write an Excel macro that ... eliminates duplicate URL entries in a column"?  The text does not need the 'Please help me'; by asking a question, you are asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the case, yes, I agree with Jeffery; read the Excel Help under 'Advanced Filter' and pay attention to the 'Unique Records' section. 
 
That said, if you are looking to have only a portion of the URL searched, that'll require a little set up, still using Advanced filter. Follow the direction to set up a 'Criteria' range. For instance, if you need to remove all URL's with "google" in a column.
 
Example:

Your data table is in range A4:B10004  
A4 is a heading = "URLs"
B4 is a heading = "Sample Header"

Criteria Range:
A1 = Heading = "URLs"
A2 = Search Criteria = "<>*google*"

Advanced Filter:
In the Advanced Filter Dialog (Data > Filter >Advanced Filter...).
Select 'Copy to another Location' 
List Range = "A4:B10004"
Criteria Range = "A1:A2"
Copy To = "H1:I1" (can be somewhere else on active sheet) 
Check 'Unique Records Only'

Click OK

This will return a list of unique URLS that does not include the keyword 'google'.